# Get part of yaml file with terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, yaml, flux

I have a yaml file as given below

```
 apiVersion: helm.toolkit.gitops.io/v2beta1
 kind: HelmRelease
 metadata:
   name: "test"
   namespace: "test-system"
 spec:
   chart:
     spec:
       chart: "test-environment"
       version: "0.1.10"
   values:
     key1: "value1"
     key2: "value2"
     key3: "value3"
     key4: "value4"
     gitRepository:
       url: https://github.com/test-eng/test.git
       helmRepositories:
        - name: testplatform
          url: https://test-platform/charts
```

How I can read only part of it using terraform. Read all the contents below ".spec.values".

```
      key1: "value1"
      key2: "value2"
      key3: "value3"
      key4: "value4"
      gitRepository:
        url: https://github.com/test-eng/test.git
      helmRepositories:
       - name: testplatform
         url: https://test-platform/charts
```

I tried with yamldecode function as given below

```
flux_config       = yamldecode((data.github_repository_file.my_file.content)[".spec.values"])
```

but it failed with below error

```
  This value does not have any indices.
```

Comment: Have you tried: `yamldecode((data.github_repository_file.my_file.content)["spec"].values`?

Comment: yes , getting same error with that too

Comment: That is for sure the same output as the data source provides it? The YML file I mean. And I think I made a mistake in the previous comment, it should be something like `yamldecode(data.github_repository_file.my_file.content)["spec"].values`.

Comment: Please add the output of `data.github_repository_file.my_file.content` to the question.